# Relative coordinate in node placement

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

When I try to use relative coordinates in `\node` using the syntax: `(x,y)++(a:r)` it gives me an error, but when I just specify the second coordinate as `++(a:r)` it's like the `(x,y)` first coordinate is implicit as `(0,0)`. I wish I could place a node in a point using relative coordinates. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    % Triangle ABC
    \draw (0,0)--++(60:2)--++(-60:2)--cycle;
        \foreach \c in {(0,0),++(60:2),++(0:2)}
    \draw[fill] \c circle (.05);
    \node [above] at ++(60:2) {\( A \)};
    \node [right] at ++(0:2) {\( B \)};
    \node [left] at (0,0) {\( C \)};
    % Triangle EFG
    \draw (4,0)--++(60:2)--++(-60:2)--cycle;
        \foreach \c in {(4,0),(4,0)++(60:2),(4,0)++(0:2)}
    \draw[fill] \c circle (.05);
    \node [above] at ++(60:2) {\( E \)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It would be very easy to place the node `E` if I could write its point as `(4,0)++(60:2)`. How can I specify it using relative coordinates in `node`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relative placement does indeed start at `(0,0)` if there is no `\pgfpathmoveto` beforehand. Basically the rule for `++(a)` is: move from the last position on this path expression `a` onwards, be it component-wise for `++(x,y)` or with angle as in `++(a:r)`. You do need that anchor though.

As the implication is that it starts at `(0,0)` you should consider using a scope with a shift or simply using `\path (4,0) node[above] at (60:6) {}`.

One option:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    % Triangle ABC
    \draw (0,0)--++(60:2)--++(-60:2)--cycle;
        \foreach \c in {(0,0),++(60:2),++(0:2)}
    \draw[fill] \c circle (.05);
    \node [above] at ++(60:2) {\( A \)};
    \node [right] at ++(0:2) {\( B \)};
    \node [left] at (0,0) {\( C \)};
    % Triangle EFG
    \draw (4,0)--++(60:2)--++(-60:2)--cycle;
        \foreach \c in {(4,0),(4,0)++(60:2),(4,0)++(0:2)}
    \draw[fill] \c circle (.05);
    \path (4,0) node [above] at ++(60:6) {\( E \)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Another one:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    % Triangle ABC
    \draw (0,0)--++(60:2)--++(-60:2)--cycle;
    \foreach \c in {(0,0),++(60:2),++(0:2)}
      \draw[fill] \c circle (.05);
    \node [above] at ++(60:2) {\( A \)};
    \node [right] at ++(0:2) {\( B \)};
    \node [left] at (0,0) {\( C \)};
    % Triangle EFG
    \begin{scope}[shift={(4,0)}]
    \draw (0,0)--++(60:2)--++(-60:2)--cycle;
    \foreach \c in {(0,0),++(60:2),++(0:2)}
      \draw[fill] \c circle (.05);
    \path node [above] at ++(60:6) {\( E \)};
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank a lot! I didn't know about the shift option and it worked really tidy!